# Method overloaded with "params" keyword behavior

Tags: c#

```
public void Function<T>(params T[] list)
    where T : BaseT
{
    foreach (var elem in list)
        Function(elem);
}

public void Function<T>(T elem)
    where T : BaseT
{
    // stuff
}
```

And now when I call it with `T1` and `T2` which are derived from `BaseT` :

```
Function(new T1()); // this calls Function(elem) method
Function<BaseT>(new T1(), new T2()); // this call Function(list) method
```

So why doesn't the first call work like the second, in the sense that it should call the `Function(list)` method with one parameter? How does the `params` keyword influence the code?

Comment: you can send array like `Function(new[]{new T1()});` which calls method with params.

Comment: Hmm that's not a great duplicate target actually.  There's probably a better one...